# how to cancel eclipse workspace job?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have below code for if a user forcefully cancels the job from UI but it is not working:

```java
WorkspaceJob job = new WorkspaceJob("My Job ...")
{
        IStatus runInWorkspace(IProgressMonitor progressMonitor) throws CoreException 
        {
            //Check if canceled
            if(progressMonitor.isCanceled)
            {
                return Status.CANCEL_STATUS
            }
            return Status.OK_STATUS
        }

}
```

The job never gets cancelled even if the user cancels the job forcefully through progress monitor UI.

Any help?

Comment: What is `Do something...` doing? You have to keep checking the `isCanceled()` method as often as you can.

Comment: thanks greg-449 I have corrected the comment section.. but I think you are suggesting to "check the progress monitor status very often" may be the inside the submonitor and return CANCEL_STATUS.??

Comment: What you show now will stop immediately. Your `runInWorkspace` method has to do whatever work you want to do and it has to keep checking the is canceled flag and stop doing the work if the flag is set.